# React avatar editor image data retrieval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input option and the output of that I am giving to the Avatar editor now it's editing but how can retrieve that cropped image from this AvatarEditor.my code is given below.

```
           <div class="file-upload">
            <div class="file-select">
             <div class="file-select-button" id="fileName">Choose File</div>
             <div class="file-select-name" id="noFile">No file chosen...</div> 

                <input type="file" name="chooseFile" id="chooseFile" onChange={this.onSelectImage.bind(this)}/>
              </div>
            </div><br />
            <Button onClick={this.onAvatar.bind(this)}>crop</Button>
          <AvatarEditor
            image={this.state.selectImage}
            width={250}
            height={250}
            border={0}
            color={[255, 255, 255, 0.6]} // RGBA
            scale={1.2}
            rotate={0}
            Avatar Width={260}
            Avatar Height={260}
            ref={(ref) => this.setEditorRef(ref)}
          />
```

functions:-

```
  onSelectImage(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({imageName:e.target.files[0].name})
    this.setState({selectImage:e.target.files[0]})
    this.forceUpdate()
      }
  setEditorRef = (editor) => {
    if (editor) {
       this.editor = editor;
       const img = this.editor.getImageScaledToCanvas().toDataURL();
       console.log(img);
   }
}
```

I have tried a lot to find it but I couldn't.

thanks in advance

Comment: When you `console.log(img)` what is the output?

Comment: i am getting data in base64 format

Comment: but while clicking on it i am getting nothing

Comment: pass the base64 image to `img` src attributes.

Comment: i am getting only black border

Answer (score 0):

You can get your cropped image from editor, like this

```
const img = this.editor.getImageScaledToCanvas();
```

Or to get a url

```
const img = this.editor.getImageScaledToCanvas().toDataURL();
```